# ROS - get current available topic in code (not command)

Tags: c++, ros

I want to get current available topics in my code so that I can set up publisher and subscribber accordingly. I know command 'rostopic list' would show this, but I want to get the information when my program is running.

Is there any API could do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Post edited after Gabor Meszaros's answer.

You find ROS C++ API reference (roscpp) [here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/) and - as in Python - you'll find `getTopics` method in [ros::master](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1master.html) subsection.

Here is a sample code of how to use it:

```
ros::master::V_TopicInfo master_topics;
ros::master::getTopics(master_topics);

for (ros::master::V_TopicInfo::iterator it = master_topics.begin() ; it != master_topics.end(); it++) {
  const ros::master::TopicInfo& info = *it;
  std::cout << "topic_" << it - master_topics.begin() << ": " << info.name << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with ROS API, is [getTopics](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/indigo-devel/clients/roscpp/include/ros/master.h#L113) that you are looking for?

Alternatively you can check the implementation of the `rostopic list` (it is python, but maybe there are overlap with the C++ API). You can find it [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/indigo-devel/tools/rostopic/src/rostopic/__init__.py#L1659).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I prefer the other answer where Alex gave a snippet to introduce the usage.

Comment: @linzhang.robot As you wish, I just wanted to help. :)